# Nutritional difference between uncooked and cooked sesame oil?

Tags: nutrition, oil, cooking

I like adding uncooked sesame oil in some of my salad dressings, but am now worried of the potential negative health implications of consuming uncooked sesame oil, as I've only ever seen it used by others in dishes that required thorough heating/cooking.

What are the nutritional differences between uncooked and cooked sesame oil?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because off topic.